# multiple sliders one page - Stash parse order and Playa

Tags: playa, stash, jquery

Concept is to stash entry_ids of playa entries to pass to jquery-nivoslider call, so that both the slider div and the call will not have identical slider ID's resulting with conflict.

```
{exp:stash:set_list 
name="rehab_list" 
parse_tags="yes" 
trim="yes" 
parse_depth="4"
}

   {exp:channel:entries 
   channel="rehab" 
   url_title="{segment_3}" 
   limit="1"
   require_entry="yes"
    }

    {stash:rehab_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:rehab_entry_id}
    {stash:rehab_url_title}{url_title}{/stash:rehab_url_title}
    {stash:rehab_title}{title}{/stash:rehab_title}

{stash:playa_stash_test}test{/stash:playa_stash_test}

   {exp:stash:set_list:nested   
name="rehab_update_list"      
trim="yes"
parse_tags="yes" 
parse_depth="3"   
} 

    {exp:playa:parents 
    channel="rehab_update" 

    limit="10"}

          {stash:playa_test}test22{/stash:playa_test}
               0{stash:playa_entry}|{entry_id}{/stash:playa_entry}
                {stash:playa_title|{title}{/stash:playa_title}

                {image_uploads sort="asc"}{photo_images size="thumbnail"}     
                {stash:playa_entry_img}{photo:url}{/stash:playa_entry_img}
                {stash:playa_entry_img_label}photo_label}   {/stash:playa_entry_img_label}
        {/photo_images} {/image_uploads}

   {stash:playa_summary_update}{summary_update}{/stash:playa_summary_update}
   {stash:playa_materials_needed}{materials_needed}{/stash:playa_materials_needed}
   {stash:playa_steps_taken}{steps_taken}{/stash:playa_steps_taken}

    {/exp:playa:parents}
     {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
  {/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Comment: And what is `{stash:update_ids}` giving you?

Comment: What if u use {exp:stash:update_ids} or exp:stash:get name='update_ids' instead ?

Comment: Got it outputting. Thanks! Next question is where do I apply the var I created to keep in sync the loop in the header labeling - '#slider-{entry-id}'?

Comment: Can u edit your post with solution ?

Comment: I can't get it to parse through my nested list which has my parent playa loop

Comment: Placing text and wrapping it to make a variable works prior to the playa loop, but once in the playa loop, nothing. What am I doing wrong with my playa loop not parsing?

Comment: Since you are nesting a playa tag inside channel entries, use playa's var_prefix parameter for {entry_id} and the other the playa fields: http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/parents.html

Comment: From what i can tell, using var prefix, it doesn't seem to change much. The playa loop still doesn't return anything. I did a little test, i cant even get a "test22" stashed into a var just to see if it would parse after EE read the playa loop - it doesn't. I'm gonna look harder to see if it is a typo as to why it doesn't pull the entries in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your var like this, using the trim parameter to remove whitespace and line breaks from the captured variable:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="rehab" url_title="{segment_3}" limit="1" require_entry="yes"}
    {exp:stash:set name="update_ids" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes"}
        0{exp:playa:parents channel="rehab_updates" status="open" limit="10"}|{entry_id}{/exp:playa:parents}
    {/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**Using the captured variable**

Use the `process="end"` parameter to delay the parsing of the wrapped code block until the end of template parsing (i.e. after the variable has been set). Inside `{exp:stash:parse}` tag pairs, stash variables can be accessed as placeholders in the form `{stash:my_var}`, which saves you having to use `parse="inward"` when passing a tag as a parameter.

```
{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="rehab"}
      {exp:playa:parents channel="rehab_updates" status="open" entry_id="{stash:update_ids}"}
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(window).load(function() {
            $('#slider-{entry-id}').nivoSlider({});
          });
        </script>
      {/exp:playa:parents}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:parse}


{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
    {exp:playa:parents channel="rehab_updates" status="open" limits="10" entry_id="{stash:update_ids}"}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Comment: I'm having an issue with my playa loop where it doesn't parse the playa vars and displays them with the playa prefix. This is using the process end to display my playa loop in my entry

Comment: You may need to try setting parse_depth="x" on the `{exp:stash:parse}` where x is a number greater than 1.

Comment: If you reduce the code you are now using to the minimum to reproduce the problem, and update your question with it, I will try to help further.

Comment: I reduced down the previous thought and have added a new thought line that i'd like to see which would be better and most likely to succeed at

Answer (score 1):

Snippets parse first, so your Stash tag `{exp:stash:update_ids}` gets read directly as it's written without being parse when that snippet code gets parsed. You can test that by only putting `{exp:stash:update_ids}` in your snippet.

Possible solution: Move that snippet code either into a Stash embed or regular EE embed.

Also, the limit parameter is just `limit="10"` not `limits="10"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible and less complicated if you use sort="entry_id" orderby="asc" it would in essence accomplish what the idea was